# Is concurrent STL it++ and *it safe?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, thread-safety

Given a BidirectionalIterator `it` created in a single writer thread, is it safe to increment the iterator `it++` or assign it `it = list.begin()` and at the same time have one or more reader threads dereference it with `*it` ?

PS: `it++` would be protected from ever becoming `list.end()` by first checking `std::next(it)`.

```
//
// initialization (writer thread)
//

std::list<int> list;

for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    list.push_back(i);

auto it = list.begin();

//    
// writer thread:
//

auto nextit = std::next(it);

if(nextit == list.end())
    nextit = list.begin();

*nextit = newval();

it = nextit;

//        
// reader thread(s)
//

auto & val = *it;
std::cout << val << std::endl;
```

Comment: *"Is concurrent STL it++ and *it safe?"* No.synchronization is required.

Comment: Typically different threads would have different iterators to the same container. But regardless, iterators are not thread safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both threads use the same iterator (they share the variable). it is not safe to read it on one thread and modify in another. If each thread has its own iterator (different variables) and the collection is not modified, this is OK. You can read the list from different threads. But if you do any modification to container, you fall into UB.